# Why can't I fade out this table row in IE using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html-table, row

I can't get the table row to fade out in IE. It works in Chrome, but not IE. It just becomes really 'light' and stays on the screen. I tried IE8 with and without compatibility mode.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideIt()
{
    $('#hideme').fadeTo("slow", 0.0);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr id='hideme'>
  <td>Hide me!</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button onclick='hideIt();'>Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a workaround/solution for a smooth fade?

Comment: try to set alpha as `0` instead of `0.0`

Comment: Nothing. Same as before.

Comment: @Adam: What was the reasoning that made you think changing from 0 to 0.0 would make a difference?

Comment: @Juan: I don't remember right now, but I'm pretty sure it was something with cross-compatibility.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, that's a bug (feature?) in IE.  If you apply it to the td elements instead of the tr, you'll get the desired effect.  So,

```
$('#hideme>td').fadeTo("slow", 0.0);
```

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm now.

Comment: $('tr#hideme').children("td").fadeTo("slow", 0.0); works as well. It's more useful in my case, where I had to select whole rows by rows id.
Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing, and it worked pretty good in everything, although quite complicated (and with some bugs - more on that in a minute - see if you can spot it):

```
function FadeInFrom(item,from_bg,from_fg,call)
{
    $to_bg = $(item).css('background-color');
    $(item).css('background-color',from_bg);

    $to_fg = $(item + '>td').css('color');
    $(item + '>td').css('color',from_fg);

    var anim = {};
    anim['backgroundColor'] = $to_bg;

    $(item).animate(anim,'slow');

    var anim2 = {};
    anim2['color'] = $to_fg;

    $(item + '>td').animate(anim2,'slow');
}
```

What this does is get the current color of the item, and then animates it *to* that color *from* the specified colors.

As for that bug, if you try the code above, you will notice that links and other DOM items may not be animated correctly by this. I leave it up to someone to try to find a solution for that.