# Fadeout and remove a table row is not working together at my asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, fadeout

I have the following script to fade and then remove a table row, but it only removes the row.

```
function deleteconfirmation() {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); });
    jAlert('The Answer was deleted succsfully', 'Deletion Confirmation');
}
```

So is it possible to fade out a table row before removing it? If yes, how I can do it?

**Edit:-** this is the table that will have its row removed :-

```
@foreach (var answer in Model.Answers.OrderBy(a=> a.IsRight))
{
       <tr id =  @answer.AnswersID>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => answer.Answer_Description.description)
        </td>
        <td>
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Answer",
        new { id = answer.AnswersID },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
              //OnBegin = "deleteconfirmation1",
              Confirm = "Are You sure You want to delete this Answer ?",
              HttpMethod = "Post",
              UpdateTargetId = @answer.AnswersID.ToString(),
              OnSuccess = "deleteconfirmation",
              OnFailure = "deletionerror"
          })


        </td>
        </tr>
}
```

Comment: Which browsers are giving you issues?

Comment: ...If IE, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437026/why-cant-i-fade-out-this-table-row-in-ie-using-jquery

Comment: both IE and firefox will not fadeout ,, they will only remove the table row..

Comment: I guess some versions of IE doesn't support opacity so fadeOut won't work.

Comment: but i tried it on IE , firefox, chrome and non of them will support  fadeout!!!,, i edited my original post to show how my table looks like...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$( '.mySelector' ).click( function(){
    var self = this;

    /* look the next line */
    $( self ).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $( this ).remove();
    });

} );
```

First:
"$(this)" is an object?

Try:

```
if( $(this).length > 0 )
{
    alert( 'Yes!' );
}else{
    alert( 'No!' );
}
```

If not is a object, define your object:

```
var self = this;
//OR
var self = $( '.mtSelector' );
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i tried the first option but still the fadeout will not be shown..