# jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

Since upgrading to IE11 I have noticed that the jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut methods don't work as expected. It was working fine in IE10. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

The code I am using is:

```
if($subHeader.next('.midContent').is(':visible')) {
    $subHeader.next('.midContent').fadeOut('slow').attr('aria-hidden', true);
    $subHeader.find('.sectionType').addClass('closed');
}
else {
    $subHeader.next('.midContent').fadeIn('slow').attr('aria-hidden', false);
    $subHeader.find('.sectionType').removeClass('closed');
}
```

Comment: try this  ` $subHeader.next('.midContent').fadeOut(400).attr('aria-hidden', true);`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. It does hide the relevant div but it does not fade.

Comment: Try this  `$subHeader.next('.midContent').fadeOut(200).attr('aria-hidden', true);` for more information - http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: I have found that the issue only seems to apply to table elements.

Comment: Can you confirm what document mode the page is being displayed in (eg standards mode, quirks mode, etc?). This may be relevant. You can find out this info from the F12 Dev Tools.

Comment: I have the same problem, except I get it on a `div`. Strangely enough, it works in IE11 Enterprise Mode and IE11 emulated to IE8.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the .fadeIn and .fadeOut functions are being applied to <td> and not <tr> elements because apparently IE does not support opacity on  elements, but do on td. This was my problem. When I created a class called .hidden and defined it as display:none and added that class to each td, then I could fadeIn the td elements in the row just fine.

See: [Why can't I fade out this table row in IE using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437026/why-cant-i-fade-out-this-table-row-in-ie-using-jquery)